# Trouble with angularjs and setting up a custom repeater directive

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make a custom repeater just to get a hang on how custom directives work and I'm not getting any errors or warnings but I'm not seeing my console log either. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<ion-item data-ng-repeat="object in objects" customRepeater>
    <p>{{ object }}</p>
</ion-item>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

.directive("customRepeater", function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        console.log("log: ", arguments);
      };
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Could it be `hdata-ng-repeat`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Looks like I had a copy/paste mishap. Resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your directive `customRepeater` , which is **camelCase** notation, in your markup you need to attach it to an element without **camelCase** so it will be

```
<ion-item hdata-ng-repeat="object in objects" custom-repeater>
    <p>{{ object }}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: You are the most helpful panda I have ever met.